# Passing Array of objects to same class C++

Tags: c++, arrays

**Question** : Declare a class named ‘StudentRec’ with three private members: ‘enrolNo’ of type int, ‘CGPA’ of type float and ‘branch’ of type string. Declare an array of objects named ‘Student’ of size 5 of class ‘StudentRec’. Write public member functions: (i) void sort (StudentRec Student[], int N ) to sort the data in ascending order with respect to ‘CGPA’ and (ii) void print (StudentRec Student[], int N ) to display the sorted and unsorted students’ records. Write main to test these member functions.

**Doubt** : The sorting part I will do later. My doubt is if in the below code(2nd last line )  `Student[5].print(Student, N );` is correct way to call the function print? How else can this function be called via array of objects Also  `Student[0].print(Student, N )` gives correct output. Why ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class StudentRec
{
    private:
        int enrolNo;
        float CGPA;
        string branch;
    public:
        void assign()
        {
            cin>>enrolNo>>CGPA>>branch;

        }
        void sort (StudentRec Student[], int N );
        void print(StudentRec Student[], int N )
        {
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                cout<<"Student"<<" "<<i<<"   "  ;
                cout<<Student[i].enrolNo<<" "<<Student[i].CGPA<<" "<<Student[i].branch<<endl;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    StudentRec Student[5];
    int i,N=5;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        Student[i].assign();
    Student[5].print(Student,  N );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Student[5].print(Student,  N );` invokes *undefined behavior* as your array only has a size of 5 (meaning the last valid index is 4)

Comment: There **is** no `Student[5]`. Has your course explained how basic array indexing works yet?

Comment: On a different note - why are `sort` and `print` non-`static` member functions? They don't rely on the instance

Comment: I understand there is no `Student[5]`. But how to do it. Even `Student[0]`, `Student[100]`,all are giving correct output. Why? And what is the better way to pass Student via print member function

Comment: It probably _happens to work_ because the index doesn't matter; your instance method never actually does anything with the instance on which it's called, only the arguments it's passed. It's still UB, though: you can't index out-of-bounds, and on top of that, nor can you call a method on an object that doesn't exist, which is what indexing-out-of-bounds gives you. And this - having instance functions that don't work on the instance, having an class work on an array of itself, using C-style arrays instead of `std::vector`, and many more - is still an awful design that no teacher should hand out

Comment: So, is there any better alternative instead of using              `  `Student[5].print(Student,  N ); ` such that the above question is solved?

Comment: `Student[0].print ...` but your teacher dosen't know anything about programming and C++-

Comment: Yes. The better alternative to consider what you've been told about proper C++ practices, and how to alter the design to use them. But if you do, you'll have to hope your teacher doesn't mark you down for not following their terrible design... which would ultimately mean you were better at coding than them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `Student[5].print(Student, N );` invokes undefined behavior as there is no `Student[5]`. However, your implementation of `print` doesn't actually use the object it is invoked on, so this is probably why this works in practice.

To give your program a somewhat reasonable design while keeping as close to the assignment as possible, you can declare the functions `static`:

```
static void print(StudentRec Student[], int N );
```

This means that, while the functions are declared inside the class and have access to private members of objects of the class, they don't rely on any concrete object to be invoked. You can then use them like this:

```
StudentRec::print(Student, N);
```

On a side note, your implementation of `print` doesn't actually use the parameter `N`.

Comment: Yes, that should remain within the wording, as a static member function is still a member function. (It's a static method, not an instance method.) Note also that you can still call static methods on instances, e.g. `someStudentRec.print(whatever, n)` would still work, though it's probably not a good way to write it, since it _implies_ an instance method.